# Line matches not showing during File Search in Eclipse 3.5 / Zend 7.2

Tags: eclipse, file, search, matching

Somehow my Eclipse (Zend 7.2) doesn't show the line matches in the treeview when doing a File Search.  It shows the files that match, but I can't unfold it to see what lines the matches are on. On my other computer at work (same software) it does work like it should.

Is there any way to reinstall the Search-module or does anybody know what could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Changed the shortcut to include the parameter -clean and now line matches are shown again !

eclipse.exe -clean
or
ZendStudio.exe -clean