# Eclipse doesn't provide details on file search

Tags: eclipse

I'm having a baffling problem with Eclipse on one of my machines, and it's driving me nuts.  When I use File Search, I no longer get the details of each hit within the files.  It used to do that, and at some point it stopped.  I can only assume that I either installed some plugin that goofed it up or fat-fingered some obscure keyboard shortcut that caused it to stop working.  My home machine, which has roughly the same setup (since I work on most of the same projects on it) does not have that issue.  Here's a quick screen shot of my home machine, which does have the details that I would like:

[image: Good screen shot]

And here's what it looks like on my other machine, with the lack of line context:

[image: Bad screen shot]

I'm totally baffled here.  Can anybody help out?

Comment: are you using the same perspective on both machines?

Comment: For those screen shots, no (one is in PyDev, the other is in Java), but it still happens if I am using the same perspective with both installations.  I just confirmed that both have the same default perspective for General | Search (None) and re-did searches on both machines using the Java and PyDev perspectives and got the same results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging [by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798679/how-do-i-get-line-previews-in-eclipses-context-intelligent-java-search-vs-c) [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451183/why-would-eclipse-not-show-search-results-inside-file-in-results-list) [items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339432/line-matches-not-showing-during-file-search-in-eclipse-3-5-zend-7-2)...

...closing Eclipse and then running it with the `-clean` parameter (e.g. `eclipse.exe -clean`) [might do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430295/what-does-the-clean-parameter-mean-in-the-eclipse-ide). Or it might not.

Answer (score 2):

One more suggestion.  This is not a nice or pretty suggestion and it doesn't tell you *why* you have a problem, but it just may work.

1. in your good machine, File -> Export... -> Preferences
2. in your bad machine, create a new empty workspace
3. import all of the preferences from your good machine.
4. If search is now working properly, then import all of your old projects to the new workspace.

This just might work.

Answer (score 2):

This is identical to this comment thread on bugs.eclipse.org -> https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=47136#c44

Unfortunately, the recommended solution is to reinstall Eclipse

Comment: I guess that's the last resort.  I'm going to try a couple suggestions here first.

Comment: Agreed mate... I was just pointing out that this is a documented issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You might try looking in the logs, to identify if there's a specific incompatibility with a Plugin.
From http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html

> Generally in Eclipse when you get an error, a message and stack trace
>   is logged to your workspace log. This is great but can easily be
>   missed unless you are looking for it. And some plug-ins silently log
>   entries to the log file. Tsk tsk. In order to never miss entries being
>   logged, we use the -consoleLog command-line argument. This basically
>   means "anything you log to the log file should be logged to the
>   console as well".
>
> ```
> eclipse -consoleLog
> ```

So, try running eclipse -consoleLog, and see if you get an error when running the search.  Do the same thing on both computers, to compare and contrast.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that might be useful in other circumstances, but I see no errors in the log.

Answer (score 1):

There are different kinds of searches in Eclipse.  It looks like the first search is a "File" search.  I am not sure what kind of search the second one is, but it looks quite different.  Make sure you are doing a "File" search on the second machine.

CTRL-h (or CMD-h on Mac).  Select the "File search" tab.  If you don't see it, then click on "Customize..." on the lower left and ensure that "File search" is shown.

Comment: The second search is a PyDev search, but it doesn't actually matter - it happens with all of the searches, File Searches included.

Comment: Out of suggestions...I wish you luck with this.